# IE browser print dialog box

Tags: vba, excel

Please help me.
How can I find out if the IE Print dialog box is open in the IE browser? I need to keep track of whether the IE print dialog is open to perform actions if the print window is open. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: what kind of actions are you wanting to perform ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I need to click the "OK" button in the print dialog in the IE browser to automate the printing process. During the operation of the macro, a new IE browser window opens with the print dialog box already open. I want that when a new browser window appears with the print dialog box, you can automatically start the printing process by clicking the "OK" button in the dialog box.

Comment: have you done research on the internet?  .... i just did a search for `print in IE using vba` and got a very useful hit

Comment: why is the new IE window opening with the print dialog open? do you have some code running?

Comment: I was looking for an answer to this question on the Internet, but I did not find it. A new window of the IE browser opens with an already open print dialog box because during the operation of the macro the web form on the site is filled and then the "print" button on the site is pressed. After clicking this button, a new IE window opens with the printable document and the already opened IE print dialog box. For automation, I need to track the appearance of the IE print dialog box and immediately start printing. I tried to press SendKeys when the print window appeared, but it did not work.

Comment: I read about the printing method via OLECMDID_PRINT. As I understand it, this command opens the IE print dialog box?

Comment: Can anybody help me? :-(